# How to keep the application running in background react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, background

I have a react native application which is doing some task and sending the data to the backend. I want this task to keep running even if the app is closed, as in the app should keep running on the background of device.

NOTE: this app will only run in android

Comment: try this library https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions

Comment: @ronakdholariya this library will not work on android 12(API level 31) or higher.

Comment: Here is some patch provide by them : https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions/issues/181 please follow it.

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to use native functionality. If you want to execute JavaScript tasks in background. Then implement it using Headless JS https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this library https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch. There's good documentation about how to set it up & what you have to do in order to ensure that the app will execute tasks even when in background/killed. This is a little bit of a grey area and background tasks are usually not 100% reliable, but this library provides good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a library which works well in Android 12 even while the screen is off:

https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer

Follow the installation and call the function like so:

```
import BackgroundTimer from "react-native-background-timer";

useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(async () => {
      callYourFunction(); // Call your Function Here
    }, 10000);
    
   // 10000 is 10 Seconds

    return () => BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(timeoutId);
  }, []);
```

This also works in iOS but stops if you keep the app in the background for longer than two minutes. I have no idea why.

(Also I tried https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions library, but this also has same problem in iOS, and it doesn't work in Android).